# What options for FLV players do I have for embedding video on a business site?

Tags: video, flv, vimeo

I'm currently putting together a site for a client, and really want video, and here I am with no experience with video in websites outside of embedding youTube videos.  They had their hearts set on the Vimeo player, but it appears as though their lisence (even for vimeo plus) does not allow its use in anything even vaguely commercial.   Does anyone know of a good alternative?  Preferably its controls should hide onMouseOut and it should look pretty sleek (like vimeo)

Comment: Have you tried FlowPlayer yet?  How well does it work for you?

Comment: I checked it out a bit, but eventually just got my Flash-savvy buddy to embed the video for me (from scratch?)  FlowPlayer is quite sexy, but their website started to frustrate me so I gave up quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also looked into this a little bit, but haven't really researched it all that much.  I don't have much experience with doing this, but nonetheless, there are two that I've been looking at getting myself: [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/index.html) and [FLV Player](http://flvplayer.com/).  Both seem pretty customizable.

Comment: you are on the same track as me! I've been checking out the FlowPlayer which looks great and has what I need.  Unfortunately their site keeps failing me.  I cannot seem to make it actually give me code to embed my own video.

Comment: Visit [this page](http://flowplayer.org/demos/installation/div-tag.htm) and then view the source.   It should be pretty self-explanatory at that point.